# get a class without a lot of if statements

Tags: c#, class, xna

I have a certain amount of classes which inherit from an abstract class:

```
abstract public class baseClass
{
    //logics
}

public class child1 : baseClass
{
}

public class child2 : baseClass
{
}
```

now I've got some management class which will have to create one of these classes depending on a enum which will have as value the same name so like this:

```
public enum ClassType
{
    child1,
    child2
}

public class Manager
{
    private List<baseClass> _workers;

    public void Initialize(ClassType type)
    {
        //what logics to put here? (resulting in correctChild)
        _workers.Add(correctChild);
    }
}
```

I was thinking of typeof but don't know quite how to implement it. 
Note: in this example it's 2 classes but in the real case it's an arbitrary amount of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the overhead of attributes and you are running this from the same assembly - you can just use the executing assembly to load the type via reflection. `Activator.CreateInstance` can take care of building the object for you dynamically.

```
public class Manager
{
    private List<baseClass> _workers = new List<baseClass>();

    public void Initialize(ClassType type)
    {
        string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        Type objType = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1},{0}", assemblyName, type.ToString()));
        var correctChild =  (baseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
        _workers.Add(correctChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this, I get one error when I'm adding it to the list. NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Danahi You need to initialize the `List` instance...that's why I did it during class initialization (*default ctor*). Ensure you `new` the _workers collection - e.g. `_workers = new List<baseClass>();`

Comment: omg newbie mistake, and I kept checking the class over and over, not seeing why it would be a null, cuz it contained values :P

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

> Creates an instance of the type whose name is specified, using the named assembly and default constructor.

so the code would look something like

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type.ToString(),assemblyName);
```

I'm actually familiar with such an implementation, i've used it myself.
I would also recommend looking into [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2008/03/31/use-the-descriptionattribute-with-an-enum-to-display-status-messages.aspx) that explains how you can actually use attributes on the enum values, to store the actual class names. You can even use it as an extension.

```
 public static string Description(this Enum enumValue) {
        Type enumType = enumValue.GetType();
        FieldInfo field = enumType.GetField(enumValue.ToString());
        object[] attributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length == 0 ? enumValue.ToString() : ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
}
```

The code will then look something like

```
Activator.CreateInstance(classType.Description(), assemblyName);
```

Comment: thank you, this is the answer I was waiting for :) a perfect short implementation of an unknown amount of classes!

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to differentiate between types.

you can use the `is` operator

```
var o = ...;
if (o is Child1) {}
```

or you could use the `as` operator

```
var child = o as Child1;
if (child != null) {}
```

or what you described yourself already, the `typeof` operator.

What I am sensing though, is that if you have a strong need for type casting, there might be something else at hand. Maybe you can solve your problem by [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). Then you don't have to distinguish between all the different types in lengthy `if-else` or `case-switch` constructions, but you can delegate the 'different behavior' to your subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use if statements, can you use case statements? like:

```
public class Manager
{
    private List<baseClass> _workers;

    public void Initialize(ClassType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case child1:
              _workers.Add(correctChild);
              break;
            case child2:
              _workers.Add(correctChild);
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well a switch will still not handle the arbitrary part.
so what I mean is, it should allow to detect new class types just by adding new values to the enum.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I thought you just didnt want to use an if statement.