# Activator.CreateInstance() specific class type instance

Tags: c#, class, types, activator

this question is an addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451697/get-a-class-without-a-lot-of-if-statements) previously asked question.

**My child classes which should be initialised and the base class which will be the list type**

```
abstract public class baseClass
{
    public baseClass()
    {
    }
}

public class child1 : baseClass
{
    public child1() : base
    {
    }
}

public class child2 : baseClass
{
    public child2() : base
    {
    }
}
```

**My enum and manager class**

```
public enum ClassType
{
    child1,
    child2
}

public class Manager
{
    private List<baseClass> _children;

    public void Initialise(ClassType type)
    {
        var temp = Activator.CreateInstance(null, type.ToString()); 
        //null = assembly which means this assembly
        _children.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

The manager class has been updated into the suggested answer from my previous question. However something is still wrong.
In the case above I get the error:
TypeLoadException was unhandled: Could not load type 'child2' from assembly 'Something'
how can I change this?
I did try some other options without success. (some resulting in a creation of the class but when adding resulting in a nullReferenceException).

**EDIT :**

Okay I changed my code into:

```
string assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
Type objType = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1},{0}", assemblyName, type.ToString()));
var temp = (baseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(objType, 1);
// 1 is the parameter I need to add to the constructor.
_children.Add(temp);
```

now I get the correct class created, but I get a NullReferenceException when I add the class to the list :(

Answer (score 1):

Likely its not finding the type because the classes are potentially namespaced.

I mean that the typename for `child2` might not just be `child2` but rather be `SomeNamespace.child2`.

**Aside** This seems like a really crazy pattern and I would advise taking a `baseClass` in the constructor instead.

Comment: could u please clarify this?

Comment: thanks, all I have to fix now is the null reference, do you have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as provided, wont even compile or work as expected also because of this: 
`Activator.CreateInstance` returns `System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle` and not actually the type you created. Of course you need to cast it to `baseClass`.

Besides that, you need to provide the name space when using this method, as suggested by Danilel.